How do you mock a Keycloak instance during Cypress tests
I have a React web-app pointing at a Keycloak authentication server, using @react-keycloak/web to connect them up.  I also have a set of UI acceptance tests, written using Cypress.
However, I can't seem to get passed the authentication stage.  Multiple internet searches haven't yielded any examples of this being done (though surely someone has in the past!).  I've tried intercepting API calls (below) but this just seems to end up in an endless loop of going application->auth server->application->auth server->....
Am I doing something horrendously wrong here?  How is it usually done - surely I can't be the first person in the world to want to do integration tests on an application that's fronted by Keycloak!
Intercepts:
cy.intercept(
        'GET',
        'http://localhost:7080/realms/my-app/protocol/openid-connect/auth?*',
        (req) => {
          req.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/?code=1234&state=${req.query.state}`)
        }
      );
      cy.intercept(
        'POST',
        'http://localhost:7080/realms/my-app/token',
        {
          statusCode: 200,
          fixture: 'authToken.json',
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        },
      )

Fixture:
{
  "exp": 2731953219,
  "iat": 2731952919,
  "jti": "e86ea719-9688-4bf2-958e-c8ecf27c3db8",
  "iss": "http://localhost:7080/realms/my-app",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "e1d4d87f-0a81-46b9-8b4e-037e136ec217",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "my-app",
  "sid": "89471cb0-59d6-4cd3-9cf7-a96e572f7b86",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "http://localhost:3000"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "staff",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-my-app"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "my-app": {
      "roles": [
        "staff",
        "user"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "email_verified": true,
  "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
    "x-hasura-default-role": "staff",
    "x-hasura-user-id": "e1d4d87f-0a81-46b9-8b4e-037e136ec217",
    "x-hasura-allowed-roles": [
      "staff",
      "user"
    ]
  },
  "name": "Test User",
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "given_name": "Test",
  "family_name": "User",
  "email": "user@user.com"
}


There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak, although it is archived it may give you pointers to where the code is going wrong.
